# Selecting multiple mysql columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I cannot figure out how to select multiple columns and a comma separated column.

I have:

```
Table: example_tbl
| amount   | recurring | frequency    |
| 100      | 150       |  8,monthly   |
| 200      | 250       |  1,annually  |
```

The problem seems to be with the frequency and the comma.  I tried:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT amount, recurring FROM example_tbl WHERE id=".$item['relid']." LIMIT 1" AND * FROM example_tbl WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('monthly', frequency));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is it you want to select?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the comma, your SQL syntax is just wrong. Connect all the conditions in a single `WHERE` clause using `AND`.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT amount, recurring, frequency
                  FROM example_tbl
                  WHERE id=".$item['relid']."
                    AND FIND_IN_SET ('monthly', frequency)
                  LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Is it valid to specify more than once FIND_IN_SET, like: AND FIND_IN_SET ('monthly', frequency) AND FIND_IN_SET ('annually', frequency)

Comment: Sure. They're just expressions, you can use them like any other expression.